# Sum columns and show totals with label with AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file with:

```
1 Inicio
1 Fin
1 Starting
1 Ending
2 Inicio
2 Fin
2 Starting
2 Ending
6 OK
4 OK
```

But I need

```
3 Inicio
3 Fin
3 Starting
3 Ending
10 OK
```

I try with

```
awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print "Total " sum}' /myfile.txt
```

But this returned the total of coincidences. I appreciate your help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk '{sums[$2] += $1} END{for (i in sums) print sums[i], i}' file

3 Inicio
3 Starting
3 Fin
3 Ending
10 OK
```

Comment: Yes, Thank You for  fast reply